# Execute code at runtime in Angular2 thats bound to lifecycle of a component from outside the component

Tags: angular, angular-components

Is it possible to execute an arbitrary code when a component is being destroyed at runtime in Angular 2?

```
class MyComponent {

constructor(private hotKeyService: HotKeyService) {
}
...

void ngOnInit() {
  this.hotKeyService.bindComponentScoped(new HotKey(...));
}

}
```

In `HotKeyService.bindComponentScoped`, I want to register a global hotkey that's bound to the lifecycle of this component

i.e In `HotKeyService` I want to unbind this global hotkey as soon as the component is about to be garbage collected i.e unbind at the end of component's `OnDestroy`

This way all components that use `HotKeyService` dont need to remember to call `hotKeyService.unbind(new HotKey(..))` in their `onDestory` method & the unbind happens transparently

Comment: implement `OnDestroy` and write your code in `ngOnDestroy()`. PS: `onInit()` in your current code should be `ngOnInit()` and your component *should* implement `OnInit` for that to be executed at runtime (though the latter isn't strictly necessary)

Comment: The problem is I dont want the users of the library to remember to this. That's why the method name is `bindComponentScoped`

I want the user to call the method once & the hotkey framework to be able to register a hook with angular framework to get it notified as soon as the called component is being/just destroyed.

Comment: If it's *really* worth it for you, you can have them subclass `MyComponent`, in which case (as of a 2.4.0, IIRC) lifestyle hooks on the super class will be executed as expected. I emphasize *really*, though, because inheritance is a slippery slope, and it gets nasty fast if you slide too far.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. That should work (assuming lifecycle respects inheritance).

The question was more along the lines of, "Is there a way in Angular to hook into the framework where we can execute code bound to lifecycle of a component from outside the component"?

This way the framework author can provide this for free to all developers

Comment: Yeah, not AFAIK. And again, lifecycle events weren't always respected up inheritance trees - check the changelog to see which version that fix landed in.